# Enable Incoming Telnet connection on Mac OS 10.12

Tags: macos, daemon, telnet

I could not find anything other than the command below but this did not work either. I need to allow an incoming telnet connection from a PC app to connect to my Mac. I know SSH is better but I have to have telnet to connect to my Mac OS. Does anyone know?

This is the only thing I found to allow the incoming telnet connection, however this did not work.

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/telnet.plist

-Seth

Answer (score 0):

According to apple support :
You can’t use Telnet to log in to your Mac.

see [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25252?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: It's funny that the link 404'd

Comment: it is happens that they delete links @lazaruslarue